# Getting an error while starting Grails

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

I get the following error when I start Grails.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:504)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:308)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:271)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
```

> My versions are follows | Grails Version: 3.1.1 | Groovy Version:
>   2.4.5 | JVM Version: 1.8.0_65

Answer (score 1):

I had a halfbaked grails-app folder in my root folder and hence it was causing issues, once I deleted that, the error went away. I hope this helps people, who see the same issue.